# Is possible to opacity this div?

Tags: css

I have this html code:

```
<div>
<img src="...." />
<a href="....">...</a>
</div>
```

This is what I want:

When the **a** link is visited, then ALL div content is set with 0.5 opacity.
Is this possible with css ?

Comment: With pure CSS, not possible until the parent selector is supported.

Comment: You mean is visited before or when someone clicks on it?

Comment: You'll have to wait for CSS 4

Comment: visited: after the user clicked on it.